# Reload crontab from php , is it possible?

Tags: php, cron

I have a question, is it possible to reload crontab from PHP?

I am changing crontab using php but I can't reload it.

Comment: Is this running CLI or via a web server? What user is it being run as.

Answer (score 0):

Given the right permissions you can execute any shell command from PHP using `shell_exec`.

Comment: Is there other option? If im not sure about permissions.

Comment: Im beginner. Im using xampp - localhost. But if I upload my application on server without right permission, how i can crontab reload?

Comment: @mirec_c You can't. Permissions are there to protect vulnerable parts of the system so there is no workaround.

Comment: Can I have a question? If I put in crontab command, which will be performed every minute, crontab will be read by cron every minute or just first time.

Comment: shell_exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\file\\Crontab -p"); is this correct?

Comment: @mirec_c Do yourself a favour and do some research on what crontab is and does, it will make this process much easier, here's a quick primer http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial

Comment: crontab does not exist on Windows. It is called scheduled tasks and the way you interact with it is completely different. See my blog for more information http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/374209271/linux-to-windows-server-migrating-and-securing-your-cron